# Windows internet connection keeps on fluctuating

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet, proxy

I am having a problem with my internet connection. After every 5-10 minutes it shows
"No Internet
There is something wrong with the proxy server
ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED"
[No Internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II1Uw.png)

After which I open proxy settings in Network and Internet and And turn on and off the use setup script option. After which the internet works fine for the next 5-10 minutes. Why is this happening? What should I do?

Comment: Unless you really use a proxy to connect to the Internet, you are better off unchecking the "Automatic network discovery" option in your Internet options, and make sure the all the proxy-related boxes are left unchecked. Tell us more about your network setup (modem, how you connect, via WiFi or Ethernet, how many devices are connected in total, etc...).

Comment: Yes I have kept the "Automatic network discovery" option checked, and all other options unchecked. I connect to internet via Wifi, only my laptop is connected to it.

Comment: Uncheck "Automatic network discovery", very often that's where the problem lies. Reboot your PC with Fast Startup disabled.